# Differences between source code and byte-code to load into jvm?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode

Every java developer knows that, in java language, at first, source code is compiled into byte-code at first, and then, jvm load the byte-code to translate it into machine language.
It means bytecode is not executed directly.
Well, but what is differences between source code and byte-code to load into jvm?
my mean is, if jvm would loaded source code 
instead of byte-code?
In the python language, source code is cross platform. python developers can compile or interpret thier source code. In any case source code or byte-code should translate into machine code. now, this is my question: what is differences between source and byte-code to load into jvm to translate into machine code?

Comment: You need a compiler to turn source code to byte code. And a different compiler for every language you want to use. The byte code is the same for all languages, and much simpler (at least for machines) than source code. The Scala compiler takes *forever* to compile source code, but thankfully the resulting byte code loads very fast.

Comment: yes, but why I need to compile source code into byte-code in java. do you know python language?

Comment: Java prides itself on being "compile once, run anywhere". The byte-code that the compiler generates is how it does that: the JVM sees the byte-code and know how to map it to machine instructions *on the machine that the JVM is running on*.

Comment: _First:_ Since java 9 there is the JShell incorporated in java for immediately executing java.  _And then:_ byte code is a compiled product, with copied imported constants, and other linkage info. For **interpreted** languages: **Smalltalk** is very nice.

Comment: Do you know the python language? Hint: python reads your python code, and writes pyc files from that. The python interpreter *also* doesn't interpret python directly, it also uses an "intermediate" representation that is better suited for interpreting!

Comment: And then: you should understand the fact that the JVM **only** reads byte code is one of the greatest things about the JVM as a platform. As it enables many other languages, such as Scala, Kotlin, Clojure, ... to write code for the JVM platform. So you can use completely different source languages than java, and still enjoy all the libraries and frameworks and advanced technologies that the JVM has to offer!

Comment: Yes, Python can translate to byte-code too. And I know the byte-code let the java platform to developed the java language. For example Kotlin, Scala and Groogy. Well when I want to run a program in java platform, what is differences between source code and byte-code to load into jvm? In any cases none are executed directly

Answer (score 0):

Byte code is intermediate code between source code and machine code that is executed by a so called virtual machine. This makes byte code portable across multiple platforms (combination of hardware and operating system) as long as a virtual machine is implemented on that platform.

Source code is code written according to a programming language specification, could be compiled or interpreted, and can be executed. Human readable, may or may not be cross platform.

Comment: That's pint, Java source code is cross platform, just like byte-code.

Comment: Source code , is the textual or high level program that we write , so yes if the text can be read and compiled and run by your device say mobile , then its cross -platform.

Comment: Java Designers want to keep  executing  environment light so the didn't want compiler to be part of JRE , and just created a lighweight executable environment  which could translate the byte code generated by compilation of source code

Comment: source code can't be termed cross platform , suppose you write your code in english and i can only read chinese , so your code won't make sense to me hence it won't be classified as cross platform

Comment: but python do it so exactly

Comment: There are a lot of languages other than Java that run on the JVM. And even within Java, you get a whole lot of custom compiler extensions (via annotation processing). All these things compile into bytecode, and you can run it without needing to know what language was used to create the program.